# Problem while packaging application with electron-forge "EPERM operation not permitted RMDIR"

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-packager, electron-forge

It's been a while when I last successfully packaged a electron-forge application, so I had to repackage due to a icon change. As I tried to run `npm run make` OR `npm run package`, as the command line was doing all the work, I got a error and terminated the command.

```
An unhandled rejection has occurred inside Forge:
[Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Users\Mikey\AppData\Local\Temp\electron-packager\win32-x64\Name_OF_app-win32-x64\resources\app'] {
  errno: -4048,
  code: 'EPERM',
  syscall: 'rmdir',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\Mikey\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\electron-packager\\win32-x64\\Name_OF_app-win32-x64\\resources\\app'
}

Electron Forge was terminated. Location:
{}
```

I tried running `npm cache --force` as well as updating the node and electron-forge to no avail. I doubt if it's anything to do with the config, but I believe it was trying to access a folder for some reason even if I ran as a administrator.

Maybe a permission issue?

Comment: "operation not permitted" Do you have ne necessary rights? Did you start that termeinal with admin rights?

Comment: I should.....I started the cmd as admin

Comment: @mikey186 did you found a solution ?
Edit: I just went to delete electron-packager in the TEMP folder and it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the task manager and checking if there is any instances of your app hanging there..

It seems that some files are being used

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).